# How to implement "swipe to delete" a custom UITableViewCell in a UITableView which is not in an UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview

Can someone provide the source code to do that?
I set the data source and delegate and tried

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

but it's not working.
I don't want to add UIGestureRecognizer to the cells if possible.

Appreciate if someone gives suggestion.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What isn't working about it?  Are any of the delegate methods called?  Does the button appear but not do any action?

Comment: "Swipe to delete" the custom UITableViewCell is not working. My cell is in a UITableView which is not in the UITableViewController.
If I scroll the table, tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath: method is called; If I swipe on a cell, no method would be called. The Delete button never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Controller in your .h file is implementing UITableViewDelegate protocol, and set your tables datasource to that Controller. try this and let me know if those functions get called.

example...

SomeController.h file

```
@interface SomeController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
....
```

SomeController.m file

```
....

    myTableView.dataSource = self;

....
```

-GoodLuck!

Comment: Hi Koray,
I already set up everything, it's not working.
But I find something new:
If I create a new project, and put my view controller with a UITableView in it, "Swipe to delete" works.

Comment: I also tried put my view controller in to a UINavitationController, and made the UINavigationController as the root view controller, it also worked.

Comment: So I guess there is something wrong with the container of the view controller.
In my real project, my view controller is in a UINavigationController, and my UINavigationController is in a BaseViewController which is written by me. Do you know what should I do with my BaseViewController?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Hey awesome, happy to hear your problem is fixed, hope i was helpful. as far your BaseViewController, I'm not exactly sure whats going on without looking at the code =/

Comment: Hey, I got it!
Because my BaseViewController is a SidePanelViewController, it functions like the facebook iOS app's side panel. There is a conflict of the swipe gestures between the SidePanelController and the UITableView.
Thank you very much, koray!